# TEA Java implementation

Tags: java, encryption

I am implementing a simple TEA algorithm with example data so I know that my output text (0x53452e77 903386e3) is wrong and should be 0x7556391b 2315d9f8. Any tips?

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int L = 0x12345678;
        int R = 0x9abcdef;
        int delta = 0x9e3779b9;
        int sum = 0x0;

        int[] key = {0xa56babcd,0xf000ffff,0xffffffff,0xabcdef01};


        //Encrypt
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            sum += delta;

            L += ((R << 4) + key[0]) ^ (R + sum) ^ ((R >>> 5) + key[1]);

            R += ((L << 4) + key[2]) ^ (L + sum) ^ ((L >>> 5) + key[3]);

        }

        System.out.println(String.format("0x%x", L) + " " + String.format("%x", R));        
    }

}
```

Comment: I figured it out, turns out since the input is only 15 bytes a 0 must be added to fill out the hex number so that the length matches So L = 0x01234567 and  R = 0x89abcdef;

Answer (score 0):

The change is to add `& 0xfffffff0` and `& 0x7ffffff` to the for-loop when calculating L and R. These are known as bitmasks - masking an integer with `0x7ffffff` ensures that a 32-bit quantity can't be signed (the most significant bit is 0), whilst masking with `0xfffffff0` ensures that the low four bits are zero.

Other minor change compared to what OP has done was use `>>` instead of `>>>`, but that has no impact on the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int L = 0x12345678;
        int R = 0x9abcdef;
        int delta = 0x9e3779b9;
        int sum = 0x0;

        int[] key = {0xa56babcd,0xf000ffff,0xffffffff,0xabcdef01};


        //Encrypt
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            sum += delta;

            L += (R << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[0] ^ R + sum ^ (R >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[1];
            R += (L << 4 & 0xfffffff0) + key[2] ^ L + sum ^ (L >> 5 & 0x7ffffff) + key[3];

        }

        System.out.println(String.format("0x%x", L) + " " + String.format("%x", R));
    }
```

Comment: Can you also explain your changes and how you solved the issue?